Defining the universal twisting morphism of the bar construction
I'm currently studying bar-cobar adjunction in the simplest case of algebras and coalgebras. I'm stuck in understanding of universal twisting morphism. $\pi: BA \to A$, more explicitly - $\pi: BA = T_c(s\overline{A}) \to s\overline{A} \to A$. So,I guess $\pi(a_1 \otimes ...\otimes a_n) = 0;\pi(a) = a$ is it true? And second question is that why is $\pi$ is a twisting morphism, There are two conditions for it $\pi$ is of a degree -1 and $\pi$ is a solution to a Maurer-Cartan equation. But I dont get why is $deg(\pi)=-1$ my literature is Algebraic Operads by J.-L. Loday and B.Valette. page 37.

Hi, it would be good to include more context so this post is readable and answerable by more people

Hello! Thank you for your suggestion,I've added literature and concrete page on which my question arrised

The confusion arises because homogeneous elements of $T(s\bar A)$ are not of the form $a_1\otimes \cdots \otimes a_n$, but of the form $sa_1\otimes \cdots \otimes sa_n$. That's why it's the tensor coalgebra on $s\bar A$, not on $\bar A$. Thus, if $a$ is a degree $n$ element of $A$, then $sa$ is a degree $n+1$ element of $sA$. So, your definition of $\pi$ is correct, except for the suspension symbols.
Regarding the Maurer--Cartan equation, just recall the definition of the product and differential in the Hom chain complex $\operatorname{Hom}(BA,A)$, and you are done. If $(M,d)$ is a chain complex, and $(N,\delta)$ is another one, then the differential $D$ in the chain complex $\operatorname{Hom}(M,N)$ is given on homogeneous elements by $D(f) = \delta \circ f - (-1)^{|f|} f \circ d$. If $M$ is furthermore a coalgebra with diagonal $\Delta$, and $N$ an algebra with product $\mu$, then the product of two homogeneous maps $f,g$ in the Hom complex is defined as $f*g:= \mu \circ (f\otimes g)\circ \Delta$.
With this information, you should be able to compute the Maurer--Cartan equation on $\pi$.

Hello! Let's look at $\pi(sa_1 \otimes ... \otimes sa_n) = 0$, deg($sa_1 \otimes ... \otimes sa_n$) = n+$\sum_{i=1}^n deg(a_i)$, deg(0)  = 0, deg($\pi$) is not -1

We are working with graded vector spaces. A graded vector space $V$ is a collection of ordinary vector spaces ${V_n}{n\in \mathbb Z}$. So, the zero element lives in every degree. That is, $\pi\left(sa_1\otimes \cdots \otimes sa_n\right)$ is the zero element in the vector space $A{n + \sum_i |a_i| - 1}$. The map $\pi$ is of degree $-1$ if it lowers degree by $1$ at each space, i.e., if $\pi(V_n)\subseteq V_{n-1}$ for all $n$.
